# these style for natbib "Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations"

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I want to use `these` style in my bibliography which must look like the one in this capture

[image: these style]

This is my MWE file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{memoir} 
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\citep{Web01}
\bibliographystyle{these}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

When compiling with pdflatex>bibtex>pdflatex>pdflatex>viewpdf I get this error

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations
```

What could I've being missing here?

Comment: Did you try to add a local TeX directory (MikTeX names it `local root`)? You have to refresh the FNDB after pasting it.

Comment: I figured out there was a problem with the file  extension `these.bst`,  I had `these.bst.txt` after modifiying it I got another error in texmaker  `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations`

Comment: Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @TeXnician I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by removing the natbib package, no need to include any bibliography package to get this style. the code should be like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{memoir} 
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{Web01} \cite{Web02}
\bibliographystyle{these}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

this is the output of my code!

[image]

Comment: You have still included the package in your code example.

Comment: Answer corrected